# Is there a way to split a string by commas only if has at least a specific length?

Tags: python

I want to split a string by commas, but only if the splits from both sides of comma have a length of at least 3 words.

For example the text:    `"I like playing basketball, football, tennis, which are sports."` 
should be converted to:    `["I like playing basketball, football, tennis", "which are sports."]`

Comment: Hi! You could split on whitespaces (.`split()` with no argument) and count the words without a comma.

Comment: How will you handle sentences like: `I am not sure but, maybe, blah-blah-blah...` ? Will you crop the sentence by the first comma or by the second?

Comment: @vurmux Yeah, this is a difficult case. I would like to return `["I am not sure but, maybe", "blah-blah-blah..."].
Or if there is a sentence "I play football, basketball, tennis", it should remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to split the string by commas and then go through the list and if there are strings with less than 3 word join them to the string before or after and remove it from the array so that there will be no doubles.

Comment: I want something like that. But I would prefer to be able to join to the correct side if possible

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.split()`

**Ex:**

```
s = ["I like playing basketball, which is a sport." , "Furthermore, I travel a lot."]

result = []
for i in s:
    val = i.split(",")
    if all(len(n.split())>=3 for n in val):   #Check least 3 words 
        result.extend(val)
    else:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['I like playing basketball',
 ' which is a sport.',
 'Furthermore, I travel a lot.']
```

Comment: you could also use `if n.count(' ') >= 2` instead of splitting the substring again.

Comment: I have a problem in this example: `"I like playing basketball, football, tennis, which are sports."`
And want to return:
`["I like playing basketball, football, tennis", "which are sports."]`. I also rephrased my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple `list` comprehension:

```
data = ["I like playing basketball, which is a sport.", "Furthermore, I travel a lot."]

result = [sentence.split(',') 
          if all(len(chunk.split()) >= 3 
                 for chunk in sentence.split(',')) 
          else sentence 
          for sentence in data]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['I like playing basketball', ' which is a sport.'],
 'Furthermore, I travel a lot.']
```